# Is there a way to get JWT for WSO2 Identity Server password grant flow in a single call?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there a way to generate JWT token directly from WSO2 identity server for a OAuth 2.0 resource owner flow (password grant)?  Currently the identity server gives back a access token which has to be sent to validation service to get back back a [JWT Token](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/JWT+Token+Generation) .

Also an observation that the JWT Token comes back with the '/' character escaped.